# Play+Nginx and HTTPS setup

Tags: nginx, playframework

I recently switched from an Apache to Nginx as a frontend server to Play. The frontend does the encryption for HTTPS.

In my app I also have a maybe unusual case where I use the WS library to call the same app (yes, my app foo calls my app foo via WS - please don't ask).

So far with Apache I never had to care for encryption on the Play side. With Nginx it also works fine until it reaches this WS self-call. If I do not add the **same certificate** I use in Nginx to Play's application.conf, the WS self-call refuses to work. It causes a SSLHandshakeException.

This is what I have to add to Play's application.conf in order to make the WS self-call work:

```
play.ws.ssl {
  trustManager = {
    stores = [
      { type = "PEM", path = "/path/to/same/cert/as/for/nginx/mycert.crt" }
    ]
  }
}
```

And the detailed SSLHandshakeException Play throws: http://pastebin.com/dSidGSxL

And the important part (I think) of Nginx' configuration: http://pastebin.com/xrdmZiK9

My question now: Is there a way for Nginx+Play, that I don't have to configure Play for the HTTPS stuff - like with the Apache+Play combination?

Comment: Is the certificate self signed?

Comment: No, not self signed.

Comment: Please, post the nginx section where you configure SSL support.

Comment: @marcospereira Isn't this Nginx configruation I posted the SSL one (http://pastebin.com/xrdmZiK9)? Please tell me if you need more. I'm new to Nginx.

Comment: If everyone is interested I couldn't solve this issue and in the end removed this self-referring call which was the cleaner solution anyway.